# Password-less access to PostgreSQL server from MATLAB (on Windows)?

Tags: matlab, postgresql

I'm trying to get password-less access to a PostgreSQL server from within MATLAB, relying on a `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` file, as described in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

The password-less access works as desired when tried from, say, a Perl script<sup>1</sup>, which suggests that the `pgpass.conf` file is correctly configured.

But when I try to connect from within a MATLAB session, with<sup>2</sup>:

```
>> conn = database('dbname', 'user', '', 'Vendor', 'PostgreSQL', 'Server', 'dbhost');
```

...I get the following error:

```
>> conn.Message
The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.
```

Can MATLAB be made to use `%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf` to connect password-lessly?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>For example, this password-less Perl snippet works fine:</sub>

```
use DBI;
my $c = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Pg:dbname=dbname;host=dbhost',
                      'user',
                      undef,
                      {
                        RaiseError => 1,
                        PrintError => 0,
                        PrintWarn  => 0,
                      } );

( my $s = $c->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 20' ) )->execute;

printf "%s\n", join( "\t", @$_ ) for @{ $s->fetchall_arrayref };
```

<sub><sup>2</sup> Of course, I am not using the strings `'dbname'`, `'user'`, etc., but the ones appropriate to the actual database, user, etc.  Ditto for the connection parameters in the Perl example shown earlier.</sub>

Comment: `pgpass.conf` only works from programs that use `libpq`. If matlab uses psqlODBC, PgJDBC, etc then it won't see the password file. What driver does it use to connect?

Comment: @CraigRinger: I'm using one of the drivers given in http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html... (9.2 41)

Comment: OK, so Matlab uses PgJDBC. You'll need to make the password part of the JDBC URL, per the documentation, pass a properties file if Matlab supports that, or configure the password in Matlab its self (again, if it supports that). PgJDBC does not read the pgpass file. I should tweak the documentation to make that clear.